# Writing logarithm formulas on LibreOffice Math

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-math

How to write a logarithm (LOG) formula on a base different than base 10 on LibreOffice Math?

In my case, it  seems to only allow me to change the value inside the formula but not the base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I write a logarithm (LOG) formula with a base different to base 10?

To change the base use `log_x(y)` where `x` is the base.

**Example**

To display the logarithm to base 3 of 10 use the following expression:

```
log_3(10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, thanks for the answer but I think you do not understand the question. What I tried to do was to WRITE a LOG on LibreOffice Math, not CALCULATE a LOG on LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: @JoãoPaulin Apologies for the misunderstanding. Answer is updated.